# invaliduriexception with photon unity

Tags: unity, networking, photon

I am using photon unity networking right now to make a multiplayer game. When I publish to windows the build works fine, but when I change unitys build settings from windows to webgl it gives my a invaliduriexception. It also does not work when I publish it to webgl. I tried looking for a answer on google but it does not seem like anyone else has had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here I go figuring it out all by myself. It basically will not work because the photon server sdk v3.x does not have support for it. Once photon releases photon server sdk v4 it will work.